# How to test for serial correlation with pooled OLS, FE an RE?

Tags: autocorrelation, random-effects-model, heteroscedasticity, fixed-effects-model, pooling

I have pooled data for 3 years, and I have come across the problem of serial correlation. Some books mention the problem of serial correlation when pooling the data. My question is: is it possible to test for serial correlation with pooled data?

Also, when using Fixed effects model and random effects model is serial correlation a problem? If yes, is it possible to test whether serial correlation is present?

If serial correaltion is present can I use the following command in Stata: vce(cluster id). If I use this command do I also correct for heteroskedasticity?